# input type="file" not working in facebook in-app browser

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, browser, in-app

In Facebook in-app browser (fb messanger 237.0 for android) not working file input

I've tried to trigger it with js

`$('input').click();`

`$('input').on('change', function () {
    alert(1)
})`

And alert wouldn't show, "change" event not triggering

In my html I have:

`<input type="file" id="fake-file-upload">`

When load site via fb browser, and I click on this input, it triggers file manager, I choose the image I want to load, and then nothing happens, file wasn't chosen, there is no error in console and when I try to click on file input one more time it stops working, it's not opening file manager.

Comment: `$('input')` is a very general selector, espcially considering you already have an id on what you're checking - `$('#fake-file-upload')` makes a lot more sense

Comment: @Light I have 1 input in my codepen, it doesn't matter at all, But of I agree that It should be more specified

Comment: I am facing the same issue in Fb version 284 app.
I cannot upload photos taken with the phone camera but the screenshots can be uploaded. Have no idea why.